# I can't get higher resolution than 960 * 720 in Image Analysis use case in android

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am working on mobile application that's used to scan Images and process them. I am using the new cameraxAPI and Image analysis use case in it.
The problem is I need high resolution images for my model to work, and I can't get higher than 960*720.

Here's my code that I'm building the analyzer with:

```java
        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("ImageAnalysis");
        handlerThread.start();

        ImageAnalysisConfig config = new ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder()
                .setCallbackHandler(new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()))
                .setTargetResolution(new Size(2000,2000))
                .setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE)
                .build();

        mImageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis(config);
        mImageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(new ImageAnalyzer());
```

NB : although there's no 2000*2000 resolution but according to the documentation it should bring the nearest higher resolution.
Update : I'm testing with HTC desire 12+ , with API 26.

Comment: From: https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/configuration in the Image Analysis section: `Max resolution: This is limited by CameraX to 1080p...if you want a resolution larger than 640x480, you must use setTargetResolution and setTargetAspectRatio to get the closest one from the supported resolutions.` It may also help to identify devices & OS version you are testing on.

Comment: I updated my question with the device and OS.

Answer (score 0):

In my CameraX example, I am trying to set `ImageAnalysisConfig` with dynamic resolutions as per device with `DisplayMetrics` of `TextureView`.

Get the size:

```
 // pull the metrics from our TextureView
 // textuewView size : height=match_parent, width=match_parent
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { textureView.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
 // define the screen size
    val screenSize = Size(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
    val screenAspectRatio = Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
```

Set in `ImageAnalysisConfig` :

```
 val analyzerConfig = ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().apply {
        // Use a worker thread for image analysis to prevent glitches
        val analyzerThread = HandlerThread("OCR").apply {
            start()
        }
        setCallbackHandler(Handler(analyzerThread.looper))
        // we only care about the latest image in the buffer,
        setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE)
        setTargetResolution(screenSize)// set target here as screen size
    }.build()
```

In my example, I am using firebase vision API to analysis image frame and identify text with OCR.

I have also tried HTC desire 12+ resolution, which is 720x1440 pixels as a TargetResolution as my case is working fine.

Here is my app code is: https://github.com/pranaypatel512/CameraXDemo

I hope dynamic resolution may help you.

Comment: This is really good to know that the resolution can be higher than 1080p, but what I want is fixed high resolution for every frame across all devices.